# Wheatstone bridge with 3 op amps breadboard help

Tags: operational-amplifier, wheatstone-bridge

I have a wheatstone bridge like the following:

[image]

I then want to connect it to a couple of op-amps:

[image]

I tried doing it like this:

[image]

Op-amp pinout:

[image]

However, I can't seem to get it to work. Have i Connected it wrong? If anyone could show me a breadboard example of how this would look in practice it would be most helpful, as I've tried for almost 4 hours to accomplish this without luck.

Comment: Just a quick look and I see that the inverting inputs of both input op-amps are open.

Comment: +1 for including a real schematic of what you're trying to build; this makes it much easier to trace the breadboard wiring diagram. I note your 741 op amp is powered by +/-15V supplies, which is good, except that pins 7 (VCC) and pins 4 (VSS) are not connected to the supply rails on all of the devices. That alone would keep it from working. Also as Spehro noted the inverting (-) inputs are not all connected. The schematic looks valid and the power supply voltage should be enough for 741, but the breadboard wiring diagram doesn't fully match the schematic.

Comment: You have too many wiring errors . Check every pin and resistor until corrected.

Comment: That is a bit of the problem, i cannot find the wiring errors, as this is how I tried to follow the schematic. I would really like to know where I've done wrong, as it's been bugging me for many hours now. But i do notice that  as well now about the inverting op amps input of the top and bottom amps. Also when you say that not all pins are connected to the supply rails, what do you mean? Thank you.

Comment: Get an AD620 or equivalent, and be done with it.

Comment: Right now I just want to get the wiring right with the components that I have. I will however take that into consideration for future projects as it would, for sure, make it easier.